# SQL - Impersonate SYSTEM_USER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, execute

Is there a way to impersonate or change the SYSTEM_USER on MS SQL 2005?

I have many views (written by a third party) which I can not change which references an SYSTEM_USER to "ID Table".

```
... AND idCode = SUBSTRING(SYSTEM_USER, CHARINDEX('\', SYSTEM_USER) + 1, LEN(SYSTEM_USER))
```

*I do have rights to the tables that the views pull from, BUT these views have the added SYSTEM_USER.*

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [Execute As](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) Transact SQL

Providing you have the correct permissions you can execute any T-SQL as another user and then revert back to the original connection credentials.

```
Select System_User
Go

Execute As Login = 'SomeOtherLogin'   
   Select System_User
Revert
Go

Select System_User
Go
```

This will output the current connection credentials for the first and third select and output the specified credentials for the second select.